# Operators execute withing double quote when there is no space

Tags: php, operators, double-quotes

I am not sure this has been asked before.

I had old `PHP` code to grab some result from the database. I recently notice that doesn't work as expected. When I debug the code I found the issue, However, I still don'tbknow the reason behind it.

Let's say I have a code like follows,

```
$text1 = "A";
echo "BBB<$text1";  // print BBB
echo "<br/><br/>";
echo "BBB < $text1"; // print BBB < A
```

I am pretty sure that I miss some PHP basic concepts. But still I couldn't find it.

When I used the `<` within the double quote with space and without space I am getting two different results. Can anyone explain me how does that happen ?

Comment: the same output https://3v4l.org/plKlE

Comment: yes, different online editors giving different results as well. please try on http://phpfiddle.org/ which will be giving the same results as I displays

Comment: no, it's there, but the browser parse it as an html tag

Comment: using inspect elements or even printing the page source `CTRL+U` will show you that the first `BBB <A` is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display correctly the first string you should use htmlentities() function:

```
$text1 = "A";
echo htmlentities("BBB<$text1"); // print BBB<A
echo "<br/><br/>";
echo "BBB < $text1";


// BBB<A</br> is interpretted as a html tag
```